# How to place unique compound index into background with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, typeorm, database-indexes, mongodb-indexes, mongo-index

This is syntactically correct, but according to TS, this option is not supported:

```
@t.Unique("user-hash-device", ["hash", "userId", "deviceId"], {background: true})
@t.Entity('vibe_trace')                                    ///   ^^^^^^
export class Trace { 
   // ... 
}
```

(the above is not quite right, since it doesn't accept `{background: true}` there).

1. is there a way to set a *unique compound index* to the background with mongodb?
2. if so, how to declare that with TypeORM?

Comment: What does background refer to in this context?

Comment: index, indexes created in background

Comment: There is no "background" distinction anymore as of version 4.2 which came out in 2019. See [here in the release notes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/4.2/#optimized-index-builds)

Comment: strange b/c the db still stores `background` in the index models...I saw that with `mongosh`...